# Class templates: restrict the template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Can I decide which types of template classes the compiler can generate?

Say I want the next class to only be able to hold real numbers (float, double) and not integer types.

```
//can I force T to be only real number types?
template<typename T>
class RealNumber
{
public:
    T num;

    RealNumber() : num() {}

    void add(T x) { num += x; }
    T get() const { return num; }
};
```

So this should generate a compile error:

```
RealNumber<int> myrealnumber;
```

Comment: SFINAE with is_integral.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: SFINAE is for function templates, to control overload resolution. This wants `static_assert` with `is_floating_point`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can assert that the type has particular traits:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class RealNumber
{
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "Type must be floating point");

    // and so on
};
```

This will cause a compile-time error if the type isn't suitable.